# How do I fix this build error when targeting android (HaxeDevelop)?

Tags: android, haxe, openfl

I'm targeting Android on my OpenFL build (via HaxeDevelop) and keep getting this error:

'arm-linux-androideabi-g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Error: Could not create PCH

Is this an NDK error? Any advice on how to proceed?

Comment: Which ndk version are you using?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of hxcpp?

Comment: ndk-r20b (Is this what you were referring to?)

Comment: Have you run `openfl setup android`?
Another thing to try is to add the directory containing `arm-linux-androideabi-g++` to $PATH environment variable.